# Import fixed width text file into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, import

Is there a way to import a fixed width text file into mongodb and specifying the columns into a new collection?

I can import a csv which is comma delimited.

Answer (score 1):

`mongoimport` command does not provide such a way - that means you need to pre-process such file in your favourite scripting/programming language.